# Invisible tab link label on mobile web UI

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Today, when I tried to login using my iPhone 6 (Chrome browser) on the meta.stackexchange.com during the [maintenance read-only mode](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/125387022934/read-only-test-august-1-2015), I got the following message on my screen:

> [image: screenshot1]

Okay, I got the reason why the "login is currently unavailable". But, then my eyes caught the "red underline" in one of the tabs listed above (as seen in the screenshot). You can see the label is **not visible** for the *current tab* that I'm on. Just the red underline beneath it. This was the default screen loaded upon clicking the "login" link.

So out of curiosity, I clicked on the next tab to it i.e. "**Badges**", and here is what was displayed to me:

> [image: screenshot2]

Now, here the current "Badges" tab label is not visible, just the red underline beneath it. But, if look carefully, I now can see the tab name "Users" whose title was invisible in the first screenshot. So, I clicked on the "Users" tab again to see what it loads and here is what was displayed to me:

> [image: screenshot3]

Now, as doubted, the label "Users" is invisible, just the red underline beneath it. But, at least the "Users" list was shown correctly and not the login screen message.

Please note that this behavior was only occurred during the *maintenance read-only mode*. You can see the "notice banner" (in light yellow background) at the top of all the screenshots shown above. Now, I can't reproduce the error as the site is out-of-maintenance mode.

Can anyone please explain this.